# Como fazer o retorno de um calculo em JavaScript para a mesma página?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como faço para que um calculo feito na chamada de uma função em [javaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) me retorne na mesma página, pois quando faço a ação para realizar o calculo, ele me retorna os valores em uma página diferente.

**Segue estrutura do HTML.**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>  Calculo  </title>
        <script src ="calcularMedia.js">  </script> 

    </head>
            <body>
                    <h2 align = "center"> Cálcuo 1: bimestre  </h2>
                    <form name = "f1"> 
                    <p align = "left">
                    Disciplina: 
                    <input type = "text" name = "disciplina" >
                    <p align = "left">
                    Nota: 
                    <input type = "text" name = "nota">
                    <input type = "button" name = "calcular" value = "Calcular" onclick = "calcularMedia()">            

            </body>


</html>
```

**Código javaScript**

```
function calcularMedia(){

    disciplina = f1.disciplina.value;
    nota = f1.nota.value;   
    media = parseFloat(nota) * parseFloat(0.4);


    document.write("<p>Disciplina: " + disciplina+"</p>");
    document.write("Media:<font color = #FF0000> "+media+"</font>");


}
```

Comment: Joga o resultado em uma div ou input não use o `document.write`

Comment: Seria possível me mostrar como faço esse processo em código?

Comment: Cria uma div com o `id` chamado resultado, na sua função faça, `document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = media;`

Comment: Funcionou aqui. Obrigado.